# How to find a symlink when the location in which it was created is unknown?

Tags: find, symlink

I followed some slightly incorrect instructions to install my video driver.

I executed this command blindly and don't know what directory I did it:

```
sudo ln -s lib /usr/lib64
```

How can I find that incorrect symlink and delete it?

Comment: That command would either create `/usr/lib64` or `/usr/lib64/lib` if `/usr/lib64` existed already and was a directory (or a symlink to a directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ln -s lib /usr/lib64
```

If there is a directory `/usr/lib64` then this creates a symbolic link `/usr/lib64/lib → lib` (the link is broken because it's looping: it's pointing to itself), otherwise this creates a symbolic link `/usr/lib64 → lib` (so the target is `/usr/lib`).

So you don't actually need to go looking for that link: you know where it is.

Nonetheless, if you happen to want to find a symbolic link knowing its name, you can use

```
find / -name lib -type l
```

If you happen to want to find a symbolic link knowing its target, you can use

```
find / -lname lib
```

If you want to limit the matches to broken symbolic links, you can use one of

```
find / -L -lname lib
find / -xtype l -lname lib
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use `find` and search through your entire system for symlinks with the relevant name:

```
sudo find / -name lib64 -type l
```

That will go through your entire file system and look for symlinks whose name is `lib64`.

From `man find`:

```
  -type c
          File is of type c:

          l      symbolic link; this is never true if the -L option or the
                 -follow option is in effect, unless the symbolic link  is
                 broken.  If you want to search for symbolic links when -L
                 is in effect, use -xtype.
  -name pattern
          Base of  file  name  (the  path  with  the  leading  directories
          removed)  matches  shell  pattern  pattern.
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect, for the reason stated in the documentation you're quoting (-L is in effect).  In any case the original question is well-answered by Stephane's comment on the question itself.

Comment: @JamesYoungman you're quite right, thanks, answer edited. As for the original question I know, and have already pointed i out to the OP in chat and in another answer. Nevertheless, the question about how to find links is both valid and useful despite not being necessary for what the OP needs.